# перегрузка operator+ c++

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп

я написал перегрузку оператора+ для класса Dinamic:

```
Dinamic operator+(const Dinamic& obj2)
{
    Dinamic temp;
    temp.size = (this->size+obj2.size);
    for(int i = 0; i < this->size;i++) 
    {
        temp.arr[i] = this->arr[i];
    }
    for(int i = (this->size);i < temp.size;i++)
    {
        temp.arr[i] = obj2.arr[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

в классе Dinamic есть поля:

```
private:
    int* arr;
    int size;
```

Вроде бы все норм но когда я пишу в main():

```
int main() 
{

    Dinamic x;
    Dinamic y;
    x.push_back(9);
    x.push_back(18);
    x.push_back(75);
    y.push_back(74);
    y.push_back(12);
    Dinamic z;
    z = x + y;
    z.PrintArray();


    RETURN;
}
```

методы push_back() и PrintArray() работают идеально
проблема именно в перегрузке.

в классе присутствуют логи я думаю это вам поможет:
[image: вывод]

Comment: Так а где выделение памяти в перегрузке? Размер вычислен. А память-то кто выделять будет?

Comment: вы забыли выделять память под массив, на который будет указывать  temp.arr

Comment: Dinamic()//Constructor
  {
   cout<<"Constructor\t"<<this<<endl;
   size=0;
   arr = new int[size];
  }

Comment: ну а коструктор чем инициализирует этот  size? Вы же не в конструкторе инициализируете размер, а потом выполняете присваивание.... Добавьте в код ваш класс с конструктором и оператором, чтобы можно было дать конкретный ответ, а не только оператор

Comment: а кто сказал, что конструктор не вызывается?.. Я спросил о значении   size    для  Dinamic temp;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратите внимание вот на эту строчку:

```
temp.arr[i] = obj2.arr[i];
```

Во втором массиве у вас неверно указан индекс. Должно быть так:

```
temp.arr[i] = obj2.arr[i - this->size];
```

Comment: с чего бы это?...

Comment: прошу вас, AR Hovsepyan ознакомиться с математикой, может поймете.

там конструктор вызывается, память выделяется

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вот с этого: for(int i = (this->size);i < temp.size;i++). Обратите внимание на диапазон изменения итератора цикла, используемого в качестве индекса.